# Trunk based development - implementation questions

Tags: git

I am trying to move my code base to trunk based development so that all my release builds are developed from the develop branch. My question is that if I have created a release build from my develop branch and then if I find a bug in the code but since then I have already committed some changes into the develop branch for the next release and I don't want to include these changes in the current release build. Then in this scenario how can I fix the defect and create a new version of the release build with only the changes that were there before I committed the new changes. I am using Git for version control.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [original Git flow description](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). In this model, your critical hotfix is made in a branch off the released version, merged back into the release branch, then merged into your development branch.

If you find that the codebase has changed so much that merging doesn't make sense, then you'd need to fix the bug separately in both branches.

Answer (score 1):

In one project that I work on, I have a similar model to what you describe here. I create tags at each release so I know exactly what code was compiled into the release. If I want to go back to the release to work on a bug, I can check out the commit which is tagged for that release and create a new branch for my bug fix. When the bug fix is ready for a release in a new version, it can be tagged as well.

For more suggestions, you should check out [Git branching and tagging best practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165725/git-branching-and-tagging-best-practices).

Comment: So the new branch for the bug fix, when does that get merged into develop branch ?

Comment: @zakSyed That is up to you. I would merge it as soon as you finish the bug fix since I assume that you not only want to release a minor update to the current version but also want to include the fix in the next major update.

Comment: @zakSyed I should also state that I have a `master` branch which tracks the most recent release of the project and a separate `devel` branch which tracks features which are ready for the next release. In that case, the bug fix could be merged into both `master` to create a new release and `devel`.